# Spark SQL: How to convert time string column in "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSSSSSSS" format to timestamp preserving nanoseconds?

Tags: apache-spark, dataframe, hive, apache-spark-sql, hiveql

I am trying to convert a String type column which is having timestamp string in `"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSSSSSSS"` format to Timestamp type. This cast operation should preserve nanosecond values.

I tried using `unix_timestamp()` and `to_timestamp()` methods by specifying the timestamp format, but returning NULL values.

Comment: what happens when you cast that column as TimestampType?

Comment: it ignores nanoseconds, e.g. converts '2019-06-24 14:30:20.123456789' to '2019-06-24 14:30:20.123456'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the description provided in source code of TimestampType and DateTimeUtils classes, they support timestamps till microseconds precision only.
So, we cannot store timestamps with nanoseconds precision in Spark SQL's TimestampType column.

References:

https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/catalyst/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/types/TimestampType.scala

https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/catalyst/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/catalyst/util/DateTimeUtils.scala

Answer (score 0):

using cast:

```
hive> select cast('2019-01-01 12:10:10.123456789' as timestamp);
OK
2019-01-01 12:10:10.123456789
Time taken: 0.611 seconds, Fetched: 1 row(s)
```

using `timestamp()`:

```
hive> select timestamp('2019-01-01 12:10:10.123456789','yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSSSSSSS');
OK
2019-01-01 12:10:10.123456789
Time taken: 12.845 seconds, Fetched: 1 row(s)
```

Comment: Using hive it works, but it's not producing expected results in Spark SQL.